# Python threading in multi subclasses

Tags: python, multithreading, class

I have a series of classes that inherit from in a series and parallel manner and I need to use Python threading for all classes when possible. An example is below. The problem is that the Build class does not get its run function executed which is a method in the Thread class. Threading works fine in MyThread class though. Any idea how to make the Build class starts as a thread?

```
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
import time

class Build(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):    
        # This run function currently not being executed 
        for i in range(20):
            print('Second series %i in thread' % (i))
            time.sleep(1)

class MyThread(Build, Thread):

    def __init__(self, val):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        Thread.__init__(self)
        Build.__init__(self)

        self.val = val


    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, self.val):
            print('Value %d in thread %s' % (i, self.getName()))

            # Sleep for random time between 1 ~ 3 second
            secondsToSleep = randint(1, 5)
            print('%s sleeping fo %d seconds...' % (self.getName(), secondsToSleep))
            time.sleep(secondsToSleep)


# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare objects of MyThread class
    myThreadOb1 = MyThread(4)
    myThreadOb1.setName('Thread 1')

    myThreadOb2 = MyThread(4)
    myThreadOb2.setName('Thread 2')

    # Start running the threads!
    myThreadOb1.start()
    myThreadOb2.start()

    # Wait for the threads to finish...
    myThreadOb1.join()
    myThreadOb2.join()

    print('Main Terminating...')`
```

Comment: Seems to work. I tried your code and replaced one of the `MyThread()` with `Build()` and it was correctly invoking the `run()`.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: Instead of subclassing `threading.Thread` the better way to achieve what you want is to make your class instances `Callable` and just pass them to the `target` keyword arg of the `Thread` class' constructor. The advantage of doing this is you can pass in additional arguments to each Thread instance.

going with your sample code.

```
class MyThread(Build):

    def __init__(self):
        ''' Constructor. '''
        Build.__init__(self)

        self.val = val

    # this allows your class to be a callable.
    def __call__(self, val):
        for i in range(1, val):
            print('Value %d in thread %s' % (i, self.getName()))

            # Sleep for random time between 1 ~ 3 second
            secondsToSleep = randint(1, 5)
            print('%s sleeping fo %d seconds...' % (self.getName(), secondsToSleep))
            time.sleep(secondsToSleep)

# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Declare objects of MyThread class
    myThreadObj1 = MyThread()
    myThread1 = Thread(target=myThreadOb1, args=(4))
    myThread1.start()
```